# Does AWS Educate allow the creation of NAT gateways?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat

I am trying to have quick access to the internet from a private subnet. I get this error message when creating a NAT gateway:

```
There was an error creating your NAT gateway
You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: PhLNSSs-pGaEXTXgy-Xfa-MWP2msuWBlj5q4xpM3DPEhewnsJ3pTcuVIQftrI_FaPsDU74zDPp9pg8O_hdq39bTOoKBh-hKIg9Cp4EElcPOCLzXeFtFpuLYegNGXg2I-hH1dhqI-wkARlwEaUS3shD0XNCuxHoKKUpf5dyFKxKUWlSKtxPKw6rSXkvySCJ8Eq3tdTmkaFC3zUiuSCkAd_DmJRvAzD_kPlwaE_NvUi-kaGBYZOvFe4Ba6KuhDf3QkRpfnD5x-JqzjjNwaBbEOz9wUmpPzCB1HbNrDCPvvyQ5Eo9veXypMKBlZyxv7JSO7Q1QQ3PTfyRT3VSQ9_E0A8dvcN-xo4y-5r8weHgZleQz22t7uN-67bSWFkdCbKet-mPJc1gsBrO3yc-EuQL7Kz-BD8qK4xcCS8XvdFR-ue4n7zgQPnS35nvlXSBdxPk9RS05BvFWmAbrU8Q09eW83OnW03zwOrRQbYfostQ45QOnagSOK8MxEK_UFNBtBCYN7zFY8XB-7ovvbfaMqrQnsT5UPKreRL80CnGt7JLotD1mJ3A2RRzyuKNgAfe0KD6PkFxXY0ZaNRDL2LNCO5vv8qxcz_dx7e1s8kjuExyWN9phCeMRdxxuUpVMTuGAewDw37Z5FWluWYfCXf-8MfccGruQW2KuIzkTrd1CGj9x2EL5fqu38WHcOtKILILLWt6JiHNH8s2_HMrlpKxOXUHC-NiPVbcVSjbylfEa55l0-jtZRNw2C1LKGMZwjXYxWM7sJtMisYp-Xqprwh-1CwDfVygn9RwFC-49SiicPNUjOAhuHUMVqUTtZOA3117FZkY2ZsaJP29W0xC5j91AUVlYjHrkpzCdmAvNn-1F5l4NKoA6XSoOgPBkQny-JAVmwek90zUmWB1zTS7LRloG7Rm7NEpRtIQp2pBRtMG8kI9wKOo5gCvK-gWq6_jdj4KRxHHr4x_e-J2z7ozFNCC9NucbWVBeLgYY5kwivQsXqt6bgQBVZ0mtbKVHacRt3PToXwUSzgGTZwwJAVpIATBs58uF97kbGbyxz2A3UUbaUMXlxoUjD5DDZTd8yVScN7S82_L-YknHIMTFgaeSEdiOtvNASYisQEEs3cVIMesjQov-DhtQd7X_itMXt1pmT87uQLCXwsOhQ49EZlSCL_I51yKIVMPEzOyWA5poiw5AwJig
```

is there an alternative way to do so with an AWS educate account?

Comment: Decode the error message and edit your question to include it https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-backup-encoded-authorization-failure/

Comment: Unfortunately I found that AWS educate accounts cannot create NAT gateways. Is there something else I can do to avoid having to send files via SSH directly to the private subnet?

Comment: Upload them to S3, download from S3 to your instance. Probably a hundred other ways as well, a public RDS database, a public EFS share, use a storage gateway. You might also just put a NAT instance in the public subnet, which is cheaper and easy, Google how to do it